# Android radio button is ckecked but does not show it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have 2 static radio buttons in radio group in xml like this:

```
 <RadioGroup
    android:id="@id/rdg_feed_event"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/txt_feed_calendar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    **android:checkedButton="@id/rdb_feed_event"**
    android:background="@drawable/radio_group_title"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider_title"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@id/rdb_feed_event"
        style="@style/Theme.RadioButton"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_btn_left_title"
        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_normal"
        android:text="@string/feed_event"
        android:textColor="@drawable/radio_btn_text_gray_black"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@id/rdb_feed_event_my"
        style="@style/Theme.RadioButton"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_btn_right_title"
        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_normal"
        android:text="@string/feed_event_my"
        android:textColor="@drawable/radio_btn_text_gray_black"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

This all is set to fragment in its onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    mRdbEvent = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rdb_feed_event);
    mRdbEventMy = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rdb_feed_event_my);
    mRdgEvent = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rdg_feed_event);
  ..
```

When I firstly load app - the button "events" is checked and its shown in view and the expression `mRdgEvent.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == mRdbEvent.getId()` returns `true`. Then I tap on the second radio button and after that I tap to other menu which leads to another fragment(with FragmentTransaction.replace). After that I return to first fragment - again its `onCreateView` method is launched and again  `mRdgEvent.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == mRdbEvent.getId()` in `onCreateView` returns `true`. But for this time the second radio button in view is checked, not the first. But the code shows true that the 1 one is checked - as it is declared in xml to be checked by default. How this can be? Thx in advance.

Comment: Post the ' @style/Theme.RadioButton ' code. You might did something wrong there

Comment: <style name="Theme.RadioButton" parent="Theme.TextView.Size.13.White">
        <item name="android:layout_height">30dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@string/font_family_normal</item>
        <item name="android:button">@null</item>
    </style>

Comment: That's why. You're not inheriting a 'RadioButton', you're extending a TextView, so, obviously your RadioButton theme does not have the attributes it needs.

Comment: Removed style to check - didnt help.

Answer (score 1):

I delayed the configuration of the button and it worked in onCreateView like this:

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mRdgEvent.check(mRdbEvent.getId());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **android:checked="true"** in *RadioButton* not in *RadioGroup*

```
<RadioButton
        android:id="@id/rdb_feed_event"
        style="@style/Theme.RadioButton"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_btn_left_title"
        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_normal"
        android:text="@string/feed_event"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textColor="@drawable/radio_btn_text_gray_black"/>
```

Comment: Didn't help. Seems like fragment saves its widgets automatically and secondary they come with presaved values. And no matter what is inside xml.